# Каково значение и этимология слова "скаженный"?

Tags: этимология, лексика

Один из примеров применения слова "скаженный":

*Повернулся бежать на Маросейку, но воришка схватил его за рукав. — Куды, **скажЕнный**? Глянь, чего покажу. Он засунул себе пальцы в рот — глубоко, по самое запястье. Вытащил — между большим и указательным была зажата цепочка.*

В интернете встречаются такие объяснения: *Скаженный* — это в переводе с украинского языка *сумасшедший*. Сказ — это тоже самое, что и сумасшествие.

Но не очень понятно, при чем тут  *сказ*, к тому же меня интересует происхождение русского слова. Может быть, есть связь со словом *искаженный*? Кстати, какое значение у приставки ИЗ в слове исказить?.

Сейчас это слово вроде бы редко употребляется, но в словаре есть пометка (сниж.). Или его можно считать устаревшим?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительно, в современном украинском языке есть слова **сказ** и **скаженый** (по-украински "скажений"), которые в переводе на русский означают **бешенство** и **бешенный** (одним из многих значений последнего слова в украинском и является упомянутое в вопросе "сумасшествие").

Корень **kaz**, как оказалось, является общеславянским, поэтому подробности лучше выяснять с помощью этимологических словарей Трубачёва и Черных. Вот только этих подробностей там столько, что аккуратно всё это "переварить" и изложить я поленился. Остановлюсь коротко на основных моментах.

Корень **kaz** в древнерусском и старославянском связан обычно со словами **портить, вредить** и т.п., а также **метить** (в дурном смысле).

Слова **сказка, искажать, исчезать, козни, казаться** и т. п. этимологически однокоренные.

Думаю, что приставка **из** в **исказить** имеет (этимологически) свой обычный смысл: что-то вроде **полностью** [повредить].

С точки зрения носителя русского языка это слово в наше время скорее следует относить к диалектным, чем к устаревшим, я считаю.

**Дополнение**. Всё же словарь Трубачёва даёт историю этих слов намного глубже. И словарь этот появился в начале 80-х, а работа над словарём Черных (в котором Трубачёв выступил рецензентом) была закончена в конце 60-х и издавался без существенных изменений.

Приведу для примера отрывок из словаря Трубачёва (часть словарной статьи *kazati, в которой говорится о связи с *kaziti).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,  пока, к сожалению, мало времени, чтобы всё обдумать и задать вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

*Скажений* с украинского дословно переводится как *бешеный*.
А *сказ* — это *бешенство*.
*Сумасшедший* — это *божевільний*.

В переводе с украинского толкового словаря:
скажений
1) Больной на сказ; который взбесился.
*Скаженный волк.*
2) Легко теряющий самообладание, несдержанный в гневе; нестовый.
Пребывающий в состоянии невменяемости, неистовства.
Который действует по собственному желанию, по собственной воле, не взирая ни на кого; своевольний. || Значение из вашего примера.

Значение приставки *-ис/-из* здесь "*очень сильно*", "*существенно*", как в глаголах *изрисовать, исковеркать, избить*.

По Далю, действительно есть связь с глаголом "*казить*":
https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/252450

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, вопросы будут позже.

Answer (score 0):

Почитала я словарь Черных и пришла к выводу, что он не считает слова ***казаться, сказать*** и ***исказить*** этимологически родственными, по крайней мере, не подтверждает это родство.

В русском языке существует глагол ***исказить/искажать*** со значением портить, уродовать, извращать, также уничтожать, опустошать. Родственным ему является глагол ***исчезать***, а приставка **ИЗ/ИС** характерна только для русского языка. Поэтому в украинском языке существовал вариант  *скажений* — безумный, отсюда и ***скаженный***.

В глаголах ***казаться, показать, сказать*** корень kaz имеет значение явить (потом — указать и сказать).

Мне же кажется интересным то, что в словах   *показать/указать/сказать* и *исказить* разные **суффиксы**, в бесприставочном варианте *казать* и *казить*. Такое впечатление, что именно они **разграничивают семантику:**  объективно показать или субъективно и намеренно исказить. Но в словарях этот вопрос не рассматривается.

Comment: Я дополнил свой ответ (хотя это капля в море из материалов того словаря по этим корням).

Comment: Спасибо большое за kazati  и  kaziti.